# Getting number of disconnected clusters which fulfil a condition in Neo4J

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have a graph-DB in Neo4J with nodes of different types and relationships. Inside the whole dataset, I would like to obtain the number of disconnected clusters which contain a certain type of nodes and relationships.

Just to give an example, I am able to return all the nodes with fulfil the condition:

```
match (p1:TYPE1)-[r:RELATIONSHIP_1]-(p2:TYPE1)
return p1, p2, r
```

This query gives an image similar to the one attached[image].

In this regard, I would like to get the number of "disconnected" clusters only according to the nodes and relationships from the query (so in the image it would be the 27 separated clusters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Connected Components algorithm](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-algorithms/current/algorithms/connected-components/) of the neo4j [Graph Algorithms](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-algorithms/current/) plugin should be useful for your use case.

For example, this query should produce a row for each connected component in your graph:

```
CALL algo.unionFind.stream('User', 'FRIEND', {}) YIELD nodeId, setId
RETURN algo.asNodes(COLLECT(nodeId)) AS users, setId
```

Each row will have a collection of the `User` nodes in that component, along with a unique component ID (should you want one).